# Xcode 10 Objective-C #import filename completion not working

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode10, code-completion, xcode10.1

I've upgraded to Xcode 10 and realized that filename completion in `#import` statements are not working properly. Here is a small part of my project:

[image]

Here is what happens when I try to complete a filename:

[image]

I've restarted my Mac, cleaned build folders, did all the common "fixes", though nothing changed.

When I type the filename manually, I don't get any errors, everything compiles correctly, and code completion works perfectly too.

What might be wrong? Is there anything that I can do or is Xcode 10 inherently broken?

**UPDATE**: I'm on Xcode 10.1 and it's still broken.

Comment: You could file a bug report.

Comment: some time Xcode don't show suggestion when its is in running mode

Comment: @RonGahlot what do u exactly mean by that?

Comment: @matt I will. Just wanted to be sure that I'm doing things correctly and had not forgotten something.

Comment: If you’re seeing new behavior, it sounds worth reporting! Code completion is always a bit fragile, so it’s not surprising if something has gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As "zhysan" pointed out on 
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/108523
this seems to be caused by the new build system.

This works for me:

File -> Project Settings... -> Build system -> Legacy build system.